# Is there org-mode gantt view feature/package?

Tags: org-mode

Is there some sort of gantt chart view package/feature for org-mode?

I want to view my headings in the gantt chart (rather then as we see it in agenda), and at least interactively modify those schedule by following operations:

1. change the start or end date.
2. shift the time range by not changing its length.

Answer (score 5):

org-gantt.el may be the project which you seek. It seems to be in early development, so let's give it a try :)

https://github.com/HeyFlash/emacs-stuff/tree/master/experiments
http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/98012

Comment: I've looked at the org-gantt.el. As far as I understood, it works by converting the schedule to latex source code, and storing those in a dynamic block, which is not so much interactive...

Answer (score 3):

You can export Org to TaskJuggler and do the Gantt chart there. Other alternative is python-gantt, but I never tried it.

- http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-taskjuggler.html
- https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2015-01/msg00243.html

Answer (score 1):

It may be worth checking out this project which has recently been announced: https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/hve0dy/ann_elgantt_gantt_chartcalendar_for_orgmode/